# Appending values of a key before spaces

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml to insert some values but it appends the value after a space instead of before the space. The current code appends the value after a line space as shown in the YAML file below. The YAML output which is marked ** NEW VALUE INSERTED HERE**

```
prefix_state:

  v4:    
    8.8.8.8/32:
      description: GOOGLE_DNS
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - dns
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
          - BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT

          **- <NEW VALUE INSERTED HERE>**
    10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: True
      tags:
        - local
      community:
        lb:
          - <NEW VALUE INSERTED HERE>
```

The code used to append the values in the yaml file is as below:

````py
yamldata=yaml.load(prefix_state_data,Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
for arg in argv:
  if arg is None:
    pass
  else:
    for i in yamldata['prefix_state']['v4']:
      if yamldata['prefix_state']['v4'][i]['community']['lb'] is not None:
        yamldata['prefix_state']['v4'][i]['community']['lb'].append(arg+'_NO_EXPORT')
      else:
        yamldata['prefix_state']['v4'][i]['community']['lb']=[arg+'_NO_EXPORT']```

Expected end result is as below:

  v4:    
     8.8.8.8/32:
      description: GOOGLE_DNS
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - dns
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELECOM_NO_EXPORT
          - BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT
          **- <NEW VALUE INSERTED HERE>**

    10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: True
      tags:
        - local
      community:
        lb:
          - <NEW VALUE INSERTED HERE>
````

Comment: Hard to see the difference.

Comment: If you look at the 1st yml file. it shows a line after BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT and then the new community
But what i am expecting is the new value before the blank line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ruamel.yaml, comments, and empty lines are associated **with the element
before them**: if they follow a key-value pair they are associated with
the preceding key, if they follow a sequence they are associated with
the index of the element they follow.

You seem to mistakingly assume your "empty" line is "after" the
sequence, or maybe even between the keys `8.8.8.8/32` and
`10.10.1.0/24`. ruamel.yaml has no such concepts and none of the
documentation or answers here on StackOverflow make that kind of a
claim AFAIK (and if they do please point out where you got to this
misinformation).

---

Assuming you have a sequence with a comment consisting of one or more
lines (and empty lines are considered comments without a starting #),
after a specific index (which maybe the index of the last item, as in
your case), you can do one of two things:

- insert a new item after the existing item that has the comment, and
  move the comment (inserting after the last item is the same as
  appending)
- insert the old item before its original position and overwrite the
  original old item, which is now one index further, with the new
  item. The comment/empty line will now be associated with the

Since the second option is more easy to accomplish, I'll use that here

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

arg = 'XXX'

yaml_str = """\
prefix_state:
  v4:    
    8.8.8.8/32:
      description: GOOGLE_DNS
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - dns
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
          - BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT

    10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: True
      tags:
        - local
      community:
        lb:
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yd = data['prefix_state']['v4']
for i in yd:
    if yd[i]['community']['lb'] is not None:
        lb = yd[i]['community']['lb']
        lb.insert(len(lb)-2, lb[len(lb)-1])
        lb[-1] = arg + '_NO_EXPORT'
    else:
        yd[i]['community']['lb'] = [arg + '_NO_EXPORT']
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
prefix_state:
  v4:
    8.8.8.8/32:
      description: GOOGLE_DNS
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - dns
      community:
        lb:
          - SELF_NO_EXPORT
          - BUSINESS_NO_EXPORT
          - TELCOM_NO_EXPORT
          - XXX_NO_EXPORT

    10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - local
      community:
        lb:
          - XXX_NO_EXPORT
```

---

Please note that the file format is YAML, the package name `ruamel.yaml`,
and that the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since
2006. But most importantly [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is something
about as old as YAML, but an entirely different format.

Comment: Thank you Sir, this works perfectly, However now have a problem with the second part too, where this shows, lb here is not a dictionary key which leads to the new community being entered in the same line of lb. 
  ```10.10.1.0/24:
      description: SELF_LOCAL
      enabled: true
      tags:
        - local
      community:
        lb:  XXX_NO_EXPORT```

Comment: It looks like you forgot the value indicator (`:`) after `lb` in the input file. You can also test if the value for the key `commmunity` is a not dict and then making it one, by using `if not isinstance(yd[i]['community'], dict): yd[i]['community'] = {yd[i]['community']: None}`

Comment: Nvm, figured it out, had entered extra codes while dumping the file into `yaml.compact(seq_seq=False, seq_map=False)
        yaml.default_flow_style=True` < This caused the problem, removed it and it worked fine.

Comment: Hey, Can you please specify what version of ruamel.yaml you used?
In the current version your method doesnt work because
```lb[len(lb)-1]``` throws and error, because you cant get item by index.